# Ask Apache if a session still exists, from an ID

Tags: php, apache, session

I would like to know how to check if an PHP session is still alive, thanks to a given ID. That or anything which could give me access to the active session's list.

I have found some related information on the internet, but couldn't really get a proper answer.

To tell you a bit about the background, I am writing a website which allows users to modify content (let's say articles, for instance). And since I don't want them to modify the same resource at the same time, I had to think about a protection's system.

So the idea was that each opened resource would be locked and associated with a session ID. When finished, the user would free it. But of course nothing prevents him from just closing the window, letting the content locked in writing.

Therefore I have to be able to check if a session is still alive, and if a lock is still legitimate.

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty simple solution for your problem:

When opening the page, store the userid and the current timestamp in some columns used for locking the element. On the page, include some JavaScript to call some script every minute that updates the timestamp - so as long as the user is on this page the timestamp will never be older than 1 minute. Simply prevent other people from editing the same element unless the timestamp is older than 1 minute (and a few seconds).

Comment: +1; however it might be more feasible to use the session ID instead of the user ID in case the same user is editing the same piece from multiple browsers or machines.

Comment: In that case he's just overwriting his own changes so he's likely to know what he's doing - besides that, losing the session (browser crash, deleting cookies, etc) would otherwise lock the real user out - even if it's just for a short time.

Comment: What you propose is indeed a possible solution. But I have to admit I don't really like the idea of prompting the database every 'n' minutes, that sounds a bit heavy.

But anyway, I am using codeIgniter's framework, and I realized it had a database session's handler, so my problem solved : I just need to pick the data I want.

Comment: (miss-clic sorry). 
Still, I will keep your idea of using the username instead of the session Id, for the reason you mentioned just above.

But, just for curiosity, would somebody know how to do what I asked at first ? Because I am sure that could be useful !

And anyway, thank you all for your answers.

Comment: A simple select/update using indexes is not a problem, even if you do it every second.

Comment: You are probably right, but I can't help to think this is overkill ... That may sound newbish or childish, but thinking about ten potential clients pinging the database each minute (while I could simply check for a session's expiration on somebody trying to open a locked file) would drive me crazy ...

Comment: At least with database-backed sessions you'd still be "pinging" the database - and if your sessions are filesystem-based.. well, a good database system keeps regularily-acessed tables in memory and the session table is a likely candidate for that (you might even want to store it as a memory-only table that never touches the HDD) - so the choice would be between "reading data already in memory" and "disk access"

Comment: Excuse me but I am not sure to understand what you mean ... Are you saying having sessions in a database instead of in a server's file is a good idea ?

Comment: It depends - but it does have some advantages (if you had multiple webservers, sessions would be shared between them for example) and you could use foreign keys to automatically delete sessions if the attached user gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I know this might be a older question but the "best" answer to your question is found here:
http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-372050.html

Here is what it says:
The php.ini file contains a setting called sesison.save_path, this determines where PHP puts files which contain the session data. Once a session has become stale, it will be deleted by PHP during the next garbage collection. Hence, a test for the presence of a file for that session should be adequate to determine whether the session is still valid.

```
$session_id = 'session_id';
$save_path = ini_get('session.save_path');

if (! $save_path) {
$save_path = '.'; // if this value is blank, it defaults to the current directory
}

if (! file_exists($save_path . '/sess_' $session_id)) {
unlink($session_id); // or whatever your file is called
}
```